# joomla template on view=category

Tags: php, html, css, templates, joomla

I make my own template , and its work well on [www.90km2.com/index.php](http://www.90km2.com/index.php)

But when I want to see com_content&view=category page on this link : http://www.90km2.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&id=23&Itemid=102

It doesn't work. Do you know why joomla didn't show my view?

I try another templates to see this page , all of them was worked well , but this view is not work with my own teplate :(

Answer (score 0):

I would try copying the template which works then modify bit by bit to get your custom template then see when problem shows up. Or create a template which has the minimum stuff in there and see if it works. Just have jdoc:include type="component"/> in the body